# Get multiple child nodes in Firebase with REST API

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have following database hierarchy in my Firebase application.

[image]

I know about [query parameters in REST API](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-query-parameters), but how can I get group1 and group2 by single http request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to get multiple nodes in a REST request is by having a query that matches the nodes you are looking for. Since Firebase Database queries don't have a `WHERE key IN (a,b,c)` type operation, the query will have to match some property value/range.

In your specific example you could order by key and limit to the first 2 results:

```
.../groups.json?orderBy="$key"&limitToFirst=2
```

But in general if you want to retrieve a set of N children through the Firebase API, it will require N calls.